# App.config: appSettings "file" attribute is not reading from the Local.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a test project, with an `App.config` that sets up default values for some settings.  I want to override these settings at the local level so each developer can, for instance, use their own credentials.

In my App.config I have the following:

```
<appSettings file="Local.config">
    <add key="Username" value="USERNAME"/>
    <add key="Password" value="PASSWORD"/>
</appSettings>
```

in the Local.config (in the same directory) I have the following:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Username" value="wayne"/>
    <add key="Password" value="secret"/>
</appSettings>
```

When I run my test I expect that getting the value of Username would return "wayne" from the Local.config; instead, it's "USERNAME" from the App.config - it seems as though it's not actually detecting that I want to override settings in another file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe it depends on how you are accessing this value within your code. I'm not 100% sure but I didn't think Local.config values overwrite App.Config values unless you tell it to do so in the code.

Comment: @AndrewHagner you do not have to due any code according to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). However, try removing the keys from the App.Config. I think the app.config takes precedence over the Local.config. I could be very wrong though.

Comment: Local.config should take precedence.  I hate to ask, but are you sure the Local.config is being copied to the output directory?

Comment: @xelco52 Haha I bet that's it.  Shows how often I bother to use multiple config files :)  Add that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hate to ask, but are you sure the Local.config is being copied to the output directory?